# Python server prints ASCII instead of integers

Tags: java, python, android, python-3.x

I'm working on an Android app that connects with a Python server. If I send an integer named Angle from my app to the python server, the server outputs ASCII characters instead of the int.

```
import socket

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 1026

server_socket.bind((host, port))
server_socket.listen(3)

while True:
    client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
    try:
        while True:
            data = client_socket.recv(1024)

            print(data.decode('utf-8'))

    finally:
        client_socket.close()
```

Background Android code in Java:

```
class send extends AsyncTask<Void, Void , Void>{
        Socket s;
        PrintWriter pw;
        @Override

        protected Void doInBackground(Void...params){
            try{
                s = new Socket("10.0.2.2",1026);
                pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
                pw.write(Angle);
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
                s.close();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e ){
                System.out.println("Fail");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println("Fail");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using the [PrintWriter.write(int c)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#write-int-) method, you basically convert the integer to character and when the server receives input, it receives text.

From PrintWriter class documentation:

> Prints formatted representations of objects to a text-output stream. This class implements all of the print methods found in PrintStream. It does not contain methods for writing raw bytes, for which a program should use unencoded byte streams.

If you want a better way, do this.
In case you want to ditch PrintWriter and send a pure integer to your server, this is what you can do:

**On your Java client**:

Use your Socket's [OutputStream.write(byte b[])](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write(byte[]))) method and pass your int.
Integer usually consists of 4 bytes.
When using this method, you send 4 bytes to your python server.

```
outputStream.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(yourIntHere).array());
```

**On your Python server**:

```
from struct import unpack

# put this in your socket while True loop
my_bytes = client_socket.recv(4)
my_int = unpack('>I', my_bytes)[0]
```

So basically every time your Socket client sends integer as 4 bytes, your server MUST receive exactly 4 bytes as this is the integer length.
And finally unpack() method will convert the bytes to int.

***Not recommended:***
If you still want to use PrintWriter, use [PrintWriter.write(String s)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#write-java.lang.String-) method to send your int as a String (make sure to convert your int to String first). Then on your python server convert str to int by simply using

```
int(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

Although this is not the best way of sending an integer to your back end, it still works but extremely prone to errors if you don't know how many bytes the clients sends. The problem is that when you say `recv(1024)` your server might get multiple inputs at once. In your case, you are closing the socket right after sending the data so you will be fine but if you plan to maintain a connection where you are sending data back and forth without closing the connection, then it will be a problem. Example would be when your client sends an integer encoded as text your server might end up getting multiple inputs at once as a string `"102030"` whhen supposedly had to be `10, 20, 30` separated, and you will not get the expected results. 
You really need to know how many bytes your client is sending to prevent that. Another thing you can do to prevent this is to prefix them with some character so your client sends `"-10", "-20", "-30"` and server receives `"-10-20-30"` and then parse them accordingly with `"-10-20-30".split('-')` python function.